# Juniper SSG Firewall - TMG 2010 publishing SSL website issue?

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, https, isa-server

I have an ASP.NET application working in HTTPS (SSL). This is working well in my local computer and Amazon AWS (production environment).

But when I host this application in office (for testing) some strange things happens.

1. I can see the HTTPS in browser and the lock sign.
2. Fiddler also shows that the output is encrypted and shows port 443.
3. But `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection` returns false
4. And `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme` returns HTTP.

In the office we are using Juniper SSG firewall and TMG 2010 (Forefront Threat Management Gateway 2010). So server receives requests through Juniper and TMG 2010.

Comment: iam publishing the site using non-http rule with a https listener which accepts connection on port 80 & port 443 with ssl certificate installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the TMG publishing rule and make sure you're not connecting to the backend server using plain HTTP.

It's possible to publish a site using an SSL listener but use plain HTTP for connecting from TMG to the server itself. In this case, as far as clients are concerned, the connection is secure. As far as the web server itself is concerned, the connection is unsecure.

Comment: if i publish using https rule with https listener i get the following error:
This webpage has a redirect loop

 The webpage at https://subdomain.domainname.com/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
 

Here are some suggestions:
•Reload this webpage later.
 •Learn more about this problem.
 
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: Does your app do a redirect to an unsecured page at any point?

Comment: No the app doesn't have any redirect's.